# CharacterController.Move in Unity character wont stop moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a unity C# script for a mouse controlled character movement system. Basically how games like Diablo work, one clicks somewhere in the game world, and the character moves to that location.

I had first tried this using the Vector3.MoveTowards method but realised that this ignored collision completely. I am now using a characterController component. I cast a ray unto the terrain to get a Vector3 position and use this to determine my movement.

The problem I am facing however is that the character does move towards the clicked point, colliding with objects along the way and sliding to the side until it is on a non colliding path again. the raycasthit seems to be accurate. but my character wont stop moving!

I even added a if clause before any movement command to check if the characters.transform.position is equal to the raycast hit position. this however did nothing. This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MouseMoverComponent : MonoBehaviour {

private Vector3 direction;
private Vector3 movement;
private Vector3 destination;
private float velocity = 40f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    //doMovement
    if(gameObject.transform.position != destination){
        GetComponent<CharacterController>().Move(movement);
    }


    //get raycast position on terrain
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 300.0f))
        {
            direction = hit.point - transform.position;
            movement = direction.normalized * velocity * Time.deltaTime;
            if (movement.magnitude > direction.magnitude) movement = direction;
            transform.LookAt(hit.point);
            destination = hit.point;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify as to what your desired functionality is after colliding with an object in the character path? Is the expectation for the movement to stop completely? If so, based on your current code, you could simply state that your `destination = gameObject.transform.position;` when a collision occurs. But, i'm not sure about the functionality you are looking to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your movement vector is never updated, you could try something like this :

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    //doMovement
    if(gameObject.transform.position != destination){
        direction = hit.point - destination;
        movement = direction.normalized * velocity * Time.deltaTime;
        GetComponent<CharacterController>().Move(movement);
    }


    //get raycast position on terrain
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 300.0f))
        {
            direction = hit.point - transform.position;
            movement = direction.normalized * velocity * Time.deltaTime;
            if (movement.magnitude > direction.magnitude) movement = direction;
            transform.LookAt(hit.point);
            destination = hit.point;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you, this helped a lot.